# How to convert a string of space delimited to a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, readr

I scraped this data from the OCC website and got returned an ascii file that is space delimited. I am looking to turn this string into a data frame.

I have tried using read.table, readr::read_tsv, but I am not getting the results desired. Below is the code to get acess to the data I am looking to convert.

```
  library(rvest)
  library(readr)

  data =  read_html('https://www.theocc.com/webapps/series-search? 
  symbolType=U&symbol=AAPL')%>%html_text()

  x = read.table(data, header = T) 
  x = read_tsv(data)
```

I would have expected t osee the result come out as a data frame BUT instead read.table() prints the result to the console with a error and warning message.

Comment: it still just prints to the console with an erorr and warning message. Would you mind running the code and seeing what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downloaded file contains descriptive content above the header; actually 6 lines:

```
Series Search Results for AAPL

Products for this underlying symbol are traded on: 
AMEX ARCA BATS BOX C2 CBOE EDGX GEM ISE MCRY MIAX MPRL NOBO NSDQ PHLX 

        Series/contract     Strike          Open Interest           
ProductSymbol   year    Month   Day Integer Dec C/P Call    Put Position Limit  
AAPL        2019    01  25  100 000 C P     0   190 25000000
AAPL        2019    01  25  105 000 C P     0   127 25000000
AAPL        2019    01  25  110 000 C P     0   87  25000000
AAPL        2019    01  25  115 000 C P     0   314 25000000
...
```

You can read it via `read_tsv(skip = 6)`:

```
library(rvest)
library(readr)

df <- read_html(
  'https://www.theocc.com/webapps/series-search?symbolType=U&symbol=AAPL'
) %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  read_tsv(
    skip = 6
  )
```

However, the first column has a wide header and there's multiple (2) TABs separating it from the next column, resulting in

[image]

You'll have to do some massaging:

```
dfnames <- names(df)[1:10]
df <- df %>% 
  select(-year)
names(df) <- dfnames
```

[image]